# Specify alternate VirtualDirectory when using UrlHelper class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I have the following web application architecture using ASP.Net MVC 5.2.2 with virtual directories for each website.

- localhost/**auth**
- localhost/**web1**
- localhost/**web2**

I'm looking to use the standard Url.Action() routing from all three (n) applications.

I have achieved a partly working example by creating an additional project to house my routing for my web applications to reference.

```
var routeCollection = new RouteCollection();
var requestContext = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext;

SampleApp.Routing.Web1RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(routeCollection);
var Web1UrlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext, routeCollection);
```

This allows me to call

```
@Web1UrlHelper.Action("Test", "Test", { entityId = new Guid() });
```

and will render me the correct URL format of {guid}/{controller}/{action} as defined by my **Web1RouteConfig** class in the **SampleApp.Routing** project.

The issue is the virtual directory of the calling UrlHelper class is retained by the URL builder.

This means (when called from web2) my url is incorrectly formatted as:

localhost/**web2**/997d0d58-5f09-4431-9b2e-88a247bd334b/test/test

Rather than:

localhost/**web1**/997d0d58-5f09-4431-9b2e-88a247bd334b/test/test

After digging I've found that I can pass into my **RouteCollection** class an instance of a **VirtualPathProvider**. This is where I've hit a dead-end.

Am I going down a rabbit hole? It sounds like I'm trying to hand-crank too much to achieve what sounds like a simple task.

Many thanks.